# How do I find the total of an alias and group is by another alias in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I am trying to find the sum of the field I have called total, in years, month, days, hours, minutes and group it by the field called Station.equipment.

```
SELECT a.Station_Name, c.Equipment_Name, CONCAT(a.Station_Name,' ',c.Equipment_Name) as Station_equipment, a.fail_from, a.fail_to,
       +CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(DAY,  a.fail_to - a.fail_from) > 1 
            THEN CAST( DATEPART(DAY, a.fail_to - a.fail_from) - 1 AS nvarchar(100)) + ' Days '
            ELSE ''
         END
       + CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,  a.fail_to - a.fail_from) > 0 
            THEN CAST( DATEPART(HOUR, a.fail_to - a.fail_from) AS nvarchar(100)) + ' Hours '
            ELSE ''
         END
       + CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE,  a.fail_to - a.fail_from) > 0 
            THEN CAST( DATEPART(MINUTE, a.fail_to - a.fail_from) AS nvarchar(100)) + ' Minutes '
            ELSE ''
         END AS total
       FROM vw_AllPotentialFailures_ByPeriod as a 
     LEFT JOIN EquipmentFailures as b
     ON a.PotentialFailure_ID =b.PotentialFailure_ID 
     LEFT JOIN Equipment as c
     ON b.Equipment_ID = c.Equipment_ID 
     WHERE fail_from between '14 Feb 2020' and '14 Feb 2023 23:59'
     AND a.KPI_Applicable = 'LiftsNR'
       order by 2, 3;
```

> 

I've copied in the code that I've written so far, but haven't managed to figure out how to sum the data yet. I'm aware that the name 'Days' may be impacting my total but I would still like to keep this formatting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: it would help if you tag your database system and add tables and data as text

Comment: Put it in a subselect and then do your sum on the above dataset from your original query.